# Collection operations with anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, lambda, inner-classes

I am trying to simulate a lambda in C#, and I need to reset a list element to the same map, but with values removed according to a list of keys. This is just using a simple list of maps.

For example:

```
myList.set(i, myList.get(i).remove(
    //not sure what to add here... need to remove a List<String>
));
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey Given that you have answered the question, which is it? We should either edit the question or retag it depending on which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the following? You don't need to put the collection back as its mutable.

```
myList.get(i).removeAll(listToRemove); // List of List

myList.get(i).keySet().remove(listOfKeysToRemove); // List of Map
```